# How to readjust all the strokes within different keyframes of one layer? [2.9]

Tags: grease-pencil

Lets say I have a layer "alphabet" and I wrote each of the letters after every 10ms keyframe. I wrote the alphabets above the line. Now, I wish to reposition the letters below the line. How can I select all the keyframe elements and readjust their position?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for **Multiframe** option

Select all key-frames that are necessary for you:

[image]

Go to Edit mode and enable Multiframe option:

[image]

Now you can select letters in different frames and manipulate like regular objects

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This is exactly what I was looking for!